# Were Sansa and Arya aware of Littlefinger’s deceptive plan all along?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

Littlefinger’s plan in *Game of Thrones* season 7 was to turn Sansa and Arya against each other, and in the end it was he who was executed. So did Arya and Sansa know they were being manipulated by him from the start and just played along to make him show his cards? Or did they learn late?

Comment: "I'm a slow learner, that's true. But I learn." - Sansa Stark

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No.

Even though the scene eventually got cut, Sansa went to Bran for help in deciding who to trust and what to believe.

> **It’s clear after Sansa turns the tables on Littlefinger that she has had some sort of conversation with Bran, but we don’t get to see it. When did it take place?**
>
> We actually did a scene that clearly got cut, a short scene with Sansa where she knocks on Bran’s door and says, “I need your help,” or something along those lines. So basically, as far as I know, the story was that it suddenly occurred to Sansa that she had a huge CCTV department at her discretion and it might be a good idea to check with him first before she guts her own sister. So she goes to Bran, and Bran tells her everything she needs to know, and she’s like, “Oh, s—.”
>
> <sub>[Isaac Hempstead Wright, "‘Game of Thrones’ Star Reveals Scene Cut From Season Finale", Variety](https://variety.com/2017/tv/news/game-of-thrones-season-finale-cut-scene-1202541941/)</sub>